# Sort data from the highest to the lowest and apply to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I hava a database structure like below (FirebaseRealTimeDatabase):

[image: Data structure]

I need to filter the data, such that I display it in a recycler view from the highest player to the lowest: (like below)

`Rico Hernandes - 40`
`Galvin Muro    - 15`
`Another player - 5`

This is the code, I'm using to fetch the data:

```
ArrayList<String> profileNameList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> profileStatusList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<int> scoreList = new ArrayList();

databaseReference.child("players")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                    //Get the Names of the each player
                    Profile profile = child.child("profile").getValue(Profile.class);

                    //Get the Scores of the each player
                    Scores scores= child.child("scores").getValue(Scores.class);

                    profileNameList.add(profile.getName());
                    profileStatusList.add(profile.getStatus());
                    scoreList.add(scores.getScore());
                  }
            }
```

I'm receiving the data but my challenge is in sorting it. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: @joe-matt is right, it will first be simpler if you just had an ArrayList<PlayerObject>() rather than three separate lists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `DatabaseReference.orderByValue()`

Checkout this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).

It will also be simpler if you just had a `ArrayList<PlayerObject>()` rather than three separate lists.